Transaction Simulation Failed When Burning NFT: Missing Edition Account Error
Transaction Simulation Failed When Burning NFT: Missing Edition Account Error
Issue
Hello Solana Community,
I'm encountering an issue while trying to burn an NFT on the Solana blockchain. During the transaction simulation, I receive the following error:
RPC response error -32002: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 2: custom program error: 0xb3; 9 log messages:
  Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]
  Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 success
  Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]
  Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 success
  Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s invoke [1]
  Program log: IX: Burn
  Program log: Missing edition account
  Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s consumed 14559 of 199700 compute units
  Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s failed: custom program error: 0xb3

Context
I'm using the following Rust code to build the burn instruction required for burning the NFT:
let burn_instruction = BurnV1Builder::new()
    .master_edition(Some(burn_data.master_edition_account))
    .metadata(burn_data.metadata)
    .mint(burn_data.mint)
    .authority(burn_data.owner)
    .spl_token_program(burn_data.spl_token_program)
    .token(burn_data.token_account)
    .instruction();

What I Need:

A simple way to burn an NFT that adheres to these account settings.
Clarity on why I am getting the "Missing edition account" error and how to resolve it.

Additional Ask:
If anyone has the time, I’d appreciate it if you could burn a test NFT on Devnet using these parameters and send the details of your approach or resolution to my wallet address:
3AUUrdUbgviVXU3yQVXiB1KbQmgGTCuHdiJ67QQPW2x3
Minting Context:
I minted the NFT using the following metaboss command:
metaboss mint one \
  --keypair ./keypair.json \
  --nft-data-file ./nft-data.json \
  --receiver 3AUUrdUbgviVXU3yQVXiB1KbQmgGTCuHdiJ67QQPW2x3 \
  --immutable \
  --primary-sale-happened \
  --sign \
  --rpc https://api.devnet.solana.com \
  --log-level info

What I’ve Tried

Verified all account addresses (master_edition_account, metadata, mint, owner, spl_token_program, token_account) are correct and initialized.
Checked the Solana documentation for required accounts during NFT burning but couldn’t identify any missing components.
Ensured the BurnV1Builder is constructed with all necessary parameters.

Questions

What additional accounts or steps are required to successfully burn an NFT with these settings?
Is there a specific order or initialization process for the accounts that I might be overlooking?
Are there common pitfalls or missing permissions that could lead to the 0xb3 custom program error during the burn instruction?

Additional Information

Environment: [Devnet]
Dependencies: [mpl_token_metadata, solana_sdk]
Steps to Reproduce: [If applicable, outline the steps to reproduce the error]

Thank you in advance for your help! Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Can you share the mint address? That would make it easier to debug.

FMTiQgHbeCsZBVVzuSmoensQnDweWeJN7fe7Aw8MtvhD @kwelliott

I've ended up not using the BurnV1Builder and instead used the BurnNftBuilder, which ended up working. I couldn't fully troubleshoot the issue with the BurnV1Builder, but I checked all the accounts, and everything seemed fine. It only worked after switching from BurnV1 to BurnNft.
